# Error using Sentry/webpack-plugin with sourcemaps in Vue.js2 + Webpack4: How to solve 'compilation.updateAsset is not a function'?

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-4, sentry, source-maps

Hi i want to connect sourcemaps to Sentry. So installed sentry/webpack-plugin But Got Errors. I don't know how to solve it. T.T

Environment :
Vue.js 2.6.10
Webpack : 4.28.4

vue.config.js

```
const { sentryWebpackPlugin } = require('@sentry/webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  publicPath: '/grems/',
  outputDir: 'my-dist',
  // productionSourceMap: false,
  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'ko',
      fallbackLocale: 'ko',
      localeDir: 'locales',
      enableInSFC: true,
    },
  },

  configureWebpack: {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js'],
    output: {
      filename: '[name].[hash:8].js',
      sourceMapFilename: '[name].[hash:8].js.map',
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
      sentryWebpackPlugin({
        org: process.env.SENTRY_ORG,
        project: process.env.SENTRY_PROJECT,
        authToken: process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
        sourcemaps: {
          assets: [path.join(__dirname, 'my-dist/js')],
          ignore: ['./node_modules', 'vue.config.js'],
        },
        debug: true,
      }),
    ],
  },
...
```

When I added sourcemaps ' assets attributes got this Error

> 92% chunk asset optimization BannerPlugin ERROR  TypeError: compilation.updateAsset is not a function
> TypeError: compilation.updateAsset is not a function
> at C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\webpack-4\lib\BannerPlugin.js:111:19
> at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
> at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
> at C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1309:36
> at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
> at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
> at C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1305:32
> at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
> at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
> at Compilation.seal (C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1242:27)
> at C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:550:17
> at _done (eval at create (C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
> at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:48:22)
> at C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1093:12
> at C:\Users\pc\workspace\skt-grems-frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1005:9
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)

How can i handle this error without upgrade webpack 5??

Answer (score 0):

I think this might relate to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68318984/8332986)

- According to this [release notes](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v4.40.0) of webpack at v4.40.0

> - new methods allow easy emitting/updating of assets compilation.emitAsset/updateAsset (instead of accessing the Object compilation.assets)

- You should try to update `webpack` to 4.40.0